# result of find in a variable with bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, find

I try to collect the result of the command **find** in a variable $REP

I try this code :

```
$REP2=$(find / -name "tokyw")
echo $REP2
```

(only one result)

but the result is  :

```
./test.sh: line 67: =/home/tokyw: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

The result of

```
find / -name "tokyw"
```

is :

```
/home/tokyw
```

Why the variable $REP2 is null?

Comment: Note that normally **find** has a **-print** flag to output. Even if your particular implementation defaults to -print, it may not work on other systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be without the leading dollar sign to assign a variable:

```
REP2=$(find / -name "tokyw")
```

Answer (score 1):

should be in this way:

```
REP2=$(find / -name "tokyw")
echo $REP2
```

note that the first line, `REP=...` without `$`